# Econometrics Random Effect model

Tags: r, econometrics, panel-data

In **R**, I wrote the following lines of code - I need to "translate it" into a mathematical expression :

```
random_effect <- plm(dvexptot ~ age + sex + educyr + inctot + hinotcov + workev + himcare,
                   data = df_clean, model = "random", effect = "individual",
                   index = c("id", "year"))
```

In the case of a pooled OLS regression, it's easy enough :

$$y_{it} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 age_{it} + \beta_2sex_{it} + \beta_3educyr_i + \beta_4inctot_{it} + \beta_5hinotcov_{it} + \beta_6workev_i + \beta_7himcare_{it} + \epsilon_{it}$$

On the other hand, I'm unsure for the random effect model

Answer (score 0):

Just add a $\mu_i$ term for the RE.